# NULL MAX(col) value even though DB has a valid record

Tags: php, sql, date, between, having

So I am trying to extract the maximum invoiceNo for current year and this is how I implemented it with PDO:

```
$sql = 'SELECT MAX(invoiceNo) AS invoiceId FROM invoices WHERE invoiceDate BETWEEN :yearStart AND :yearEnd HAVING invoiceId IS NOT NULL';
        if($stmt = $pdo1->prepare($sql)){
            $year = date("Y")."-01-01";
            $stmt->bindParam(":yearStart", $year);
            $year = date("Y")."-12-31";
            $stmt->bindParam(":yearEnd", $year);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $invoiceNo = $row['invoiceId'];
                    $response = date("Y").strval(++$invoiceNo);
                }
                else{
                    $response = date("Y")."-0";
                }
            }
        }
```

However, $response keeps getting assigned to the else clause : [image].

This is how my DB looks like: [image]

Hence I was expecting the $response to be 2022-2.

I think there is something wrong with my SQL query and I apologize for that, still learning the ropes!

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: P.S. Dare I ask _why_ you want to extract the maximum invoice number? Please tell me you're not generating these through your code instead of relying on an auto-increment field, as you should. If so, you're just setting yourself up for race conditions and duplicates.

Comment: I did set it to auto-increment before, but the requirements from the other department is that the invoiceNo should reset yearly.

Comment: Well you can generate some other number to satisfy their arbitrary formatting requirement, but don't use it as the unique identifier for the row!

Comment: Ah yes I totally forgot that I used it as my primary_key! Thanks for highlighting it, yes I will create another column to fit this requirement.

Comment: Anyway I'd expect your query to return 1, not 2. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc940f960b83a65a4a837016b32a744c .

Comment: Yes I was expecting the query to return a value, which would trigger the if clause, however, the query is returning null and thus, due to the HAVING condition, would run the else clause. could it be that the binding is wrong? Is date in databases stored as a string?

Comment: `Is date in databases stored as a string`...well it shouldn't be, it should be in a `date` column as per my demo. But obviously I don't know how you've actually stored it

Comment: `the query is returning null`...actually if it's going into the `else` associated with the `if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){`, then that means it returned no rows, which is not the same as it returning a row with null in it. It's not clear to me why it's doing that, because based on the data you've shown I've proved it should return a value. Perhaps the data in the database that PHP is looking at isn't the same as the one you showed? Do you have more than one copy of the database, or something?

Comment: (P.S. Even if you store the invoiceDate as a `varchar`, which you really really shouldn't, it would - in this case - still return a row... demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fcb6f34882559ea3527d9aec4d2d23fe

Comment: thank you for your prompt responses! i stored my date as DATE and my pdo is connected to the correct database, hmmmmm i think it might have something to do with the binding then

Comment: One thing it could be... bindParam binds by reference. So the fact you've re-used the `$year` variable for two purposes might be problematic. Try creating two different PHP variables for the start and end dates (and give them a better name, because they're not years, they're specific dates!). If I had to guess, I'd suspect it's binding both parameters to the final value of $year, which will be 2022-12-31.

Comment: HOLY SHIT i think this might be it, but I still don't understand why it works. In my original code when I passed $year to be used in the first bindParam() doesn't the function already run with the variable and binds :yearStart to $year?

Comment: No, it doesn't bind anything until the statement is actually executed. The info is all stored by PDO and then passed to the mysql server at the time of execution. MySQL then assembles the SQL and params to form the final query. Like I said, the variable is [passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). So if you subsequently update the value of `$year` after a call to bindParam, that value is shared with the bindParam context, so that when the query is actually executed, the new value of $year is used for all the parameters it was passed to.

Comment: See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(arbitInvoiceNo) AS invoiceId FROM invoices WHERE invoiceDate BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd HAVING invoiceId IS NOT NULL";
        if($stmt = $pdo1->prepare($sql)){
            $dateStart = date("Y")."-01-01";
            $stmt->bindParam(":dateStart", $dateStart);
            $dateEnd = date("Y")."-12-31";
            $stmt->bindParam(":dateEnd", $dateEnd);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $invoiceNo = $row['invoiceId'];
                    $response = date("Y")."-".strval(++$invoiceNo);
                }
                else{
                    $response = date("Y")."-0";
                }
            }
        }
```

Changed the way I named the variables in PHP and the placeholders in the SQL query. Thank you [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) for all the help!